# Flink Socket Source - words encoded in UTF cannot be read by Flink

Tags: java, sockets, apache-flink

I am trying to let Flink read some streaming text input from a socket connection.

In my input socket's code, I used the following to publish the text for Flink to receive:

```
outputStream.writeUTF(new String(message.getPayload()));
```

However, in Flink, I couldn't read the incoming text even though the connections are working. I Google-d and found that I might need to read the text using `readUTF()`. In other word it's mainly due to encoding. However, these are done on `InputStream`; Flink doesn't have that as my inputs are in the form of `DataStream<String>`:

```
DataStream<String> text = env.socketTextStream("localhost", port, "\n");
```

Can anyone advise me on this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`writeUTF()` does not produce 'words encoded in UTF'. It produces a specific format with a 16-bit length-word prefix that only `readUTF()` can understand. If you don't want to use `readUTF()` you can't use `writeUTF()` either. Use `writeBytes()` or whatever else suits your reading code.

Answer (score -1):

What is your program trying to accomplish?
These are the [use cases](https://flink.apache.org/usecases.html) for Flink, and if you are not trying to achieve one of these, I would recommend using Java [sockets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/) if you are just doing low-level network communication

If using Java, it is quite simple.  You need to get the data input stream from the socket, then convert the incoming bytes back into a string.  For example, here is what has worked for me

```
Socket socket = new Socket(HOST_IP, PORT);

DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
while ((i = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1)
{
    String input = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I'm trying to setting up a source whereby it's a socket connection. With regards to Java sockets, I am using java.io.DataOuputStream.writeUTF(String str).

Comment: I updated my answer to show a code example - hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! Now what I need to do is to apply this to Flink's datastream. This is because the data input came in the form of "DataStream<String> text = env.socketTextStream("localhost", port, "\n");". I've added this to my question. Thanks again.

Comment: This code is not correct. It ignores the count returned by `read()` when constructing the `String`.